# Add Nuxt to current Laravel 8 project

Tags: nuxt.js, laravel-8, laravel-mix

I have a current project made with Laravel 8 and Vue and I would like to add Nuxt.js.

To add Nuxt I change the package.js di add dependencies:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3"
 }, 
 "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^4.0.1",
     "postcss": "^8.2.8"
 }
```

And then created the required folders manually (*pages*, *layouts* etc...) into the */resources/js/* folder and add the *nuxt.config.js* file

Now I have to update the scripts in package.js but I'm not sure about it:

current package.js:

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
```

new scripts should be having:

```json
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt  -c resources/js/nuxt.config.js",
     "build": "nuxt build  -c resources/js/nuxt.config.js",
    "start": "nuxt start  -c resources/js/nuxt.config.js",
    "generate": "nuxt generate  -c resources/js/nuxt.config.js"
},
```

But what about mix? How should I update it?

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure that it will be that easy (if at all) to mix Laravel and Nuxt. But more importantly: what would you mix both in the same project here? Laravel is already a backend, you may incorporate Vue to it. Otherwise, use Nuxt alongside your Laravel app (used as an API in this case). This video may be a start point (vue -> nuxt): https://youtu.be/_eyGtBjNS4c But it does not change my concern of mixing 2 backends and the benefits that you may take out from this. As a comparison, it's like asking how to mix Phoenix LiveView (or Gatsby) with NodeJS in the same project, no real benefit.